# binary search in a sorted list in c#

Tags: c#

I am retrieving client id\ drum id from a file and storing them in a list.
then taking the client id and storing it in another list.

I need to display the client id that the user specifies (`input_id`) on a Datagrid.

I need to get all the occurrences of this specific id using binary search.
the file is already sorted.

I need first to find the occurrences of `input_id` in `id_list`.

The question is: how to find all the occurrences of `input_id` in the sorted list `id_list` using binary search?

```cs
using(StreamReader sr= new StreamReader(path))
{
    List<string> id_list = new List<string>();
    List<string> all_list= new List<string>();
    List<int> indexes = new List<int>();

    string line = sr.ReadLine();
    line = sr.ReadLine();
    while (line != null)
    {
        all_list.Add(line);
        string[] break1 = line.Split('/');

         id_list.Add(break1[0]);
        line = sr.ReadLine();

    }
}

string input_id = textBox1.Text;
```

Data in the file:

```
client id/drum id
-----------------
123/321  
231/3213    
321/213123 ...
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I need to find all the occurrences of input_id in the sorted list id_list using binary search

Comment: first what is your question and also could you show us some example on how the data is saved on the file

Comment: What dose 123/321 represent, is the 123 is the Id? that you need to find out

Comment: deal @Alen.Toma

Comment: question updated @dcg

Comment: yes i need to find client id  @Alen.Toma

Comment: Look at my answer and let me know.

Comment: `List.BinarySearch()`??

Comment: Do you have to use two lists, and does it have to be binary search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the requirement was to use binary search I would create a custom class with a comparer, and then find an element and loop forward/backward to get any other elements. Like:

```
   static void Main(string[] args
    {
        var path = @"file path...";
    
        // read all the Ids from the file.
        var id_list = File.ReadLines(path).Select(x => new Drum
        {
            ClientId = x.Split('/').First(),
            DrumId = x.Split('/').Last()
        }).OrderBy(o => o.ClientId).ToList();
    
        var find = new Drum { ClientId = "231" };
    
        var index = id_list.BinarySearch(find, new DrumComparer());
    
        if (index != -1)
        {
            List<Drum> matches = new List<Drum>();
            matches.Add(id_list[index]);
   
            //get previous matches
            for (int i = index - 1; i > 0; i--)
            {
               if (id_list[i].ClientId == find.ClientId)
                    matches.Add(id_list[i]);
                else
                    break;
            }
                   
             //get forward matches
             for (int i = index + 1; i < id_list.Count; i++)
             {
                 if (id_list[i].ClientId == find.ClientId)
                    matches.Add(id_list[i]);
                 else
                    break;
              }
    
          }
      }
    
      public class Drum
      {
           public string DrumId { get; set; }
           public string ClientId { get; set; }
      }
    
      public class DrumComparer : Comparer<Drum>
      {
           public override int Compare(Drum x, Drum y) => 
 x.ClientId.CompareTo(y.ClientId);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you question  right then this should be a simple where stats.

```js
// read all the Ids from the file.
var Id_list = File.ReadLines(path).Select(x => new {
  ClientId = x.Split('/').First(),
    DrumId = x.Split('/').Last()
}).ToList();

var foundIds = Id_list.Where(x => x.ClientId == input_id);
```

Comment: I updated my answer and gave you a simple way to read all the ids.

Comment: He wants `List.BinarySearch()`

Comment: Doesn't BinarySearch only return the first occurrence, and he wants all of them?

Comment: Well that is why I read all of them and then search

Comment: an excellent way to read and search but I need to use the binary search.@Alen.Toma

Comment: @CharbelEid - Right, and it doesn't guarantee the first result, so after getting an element you would have to loop forward and backward to get the remaining elements.